# error TS2707 Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type arguments

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-material

After installing angular material and adding angular material imports in app.module.ts to the project im having errors and all solutions didn't work so far. I have angular 14, node 16. First error, which in reality is way longer:

```
Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/index.d.ts:152:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type arguments.

152     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<CdkAriaLive, "[cdkAriaLive]", ["cdkAriaLive"], { "politeness": "cdkAriaLive"; "duration": "cdkAriaLiveDuration"; }, {}, never, never, false, never>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/index.d.ts:175:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type arguments.

175     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<CdkMonitorFocus, "[cdkMonitorElementFocus], [cdkMonitorSubtreeFocus]", ["cdkMonitorFocus"], {}, { "cdkFocusChange": "cdkFocusChange"; }, never, never, false, never>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/index.d.ts:208:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type arguments.

208     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<CdkTrapFocus, "[cdkTrapFocus]", ["cdkTrapFocus"], { "enabled": "cdkTrapFocus"; "autoCapture": "cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture"; }, {}, never, never, false, never>;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@angular/cdk/bidi/index.d.ts:37:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type arguments.

37     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<Dir, "[dir]", ["dir"], { "dir": "dir"; }, { "change": "dirChange"; }, never, never, false, never>;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
{
  "name": "highlight",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.4",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.11.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars": "^20.3.56",
    "apexcharts": "^3.36.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.7.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "4.7"
  }
}
```

I tried to delete node_modules, .angular and npm install. Didn't work.
Next i tried to reinstall angular material - npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk - gave me error, but different one. Im suspecting this is showing more clear reason of my actual error.  As suggested in error i tried commands npm install --legacy-peer-deps, --force, npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps ,did not work. Maybe someone have more experience and recognize the problem?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: highlight@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^14.2.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from @angular/cdk@15.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

My ng v outcome:

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.10
Node: 16.10.0
Package Manager: npm 7.24.0 
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 14.2.12
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.10
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.10
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.10
@angular/cdk                    15.0.1
@angular/cli                    14.2.10
@angular/material               15.0.1
@schematics/angular             14.2.10
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.7.4
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this.. I am facing same problem.

Comment: @ShilpiJaiswal no, so far only solution is to not use angular material :D, but it's my project for portfolio so i will need to find solution, and when i do, i will let you know. So far i suspect my mine problem is in last error which i achieve by reinstalling angular material - but the proposed solution --legacy-peer-deps and other solutions i found so far in stackoverflow didn't help. At least it was different error :D

Comment: I was facing this error for multiple libraries that solved after installing each dependency one by one like this npm install @angular/router14 --save --legacy-peer-deps but one error I am not able to overcome for ng-cirlce-progress

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same issue and it started seemingly randomly without changing any dependencies on the build pipeline. I am on Angular 14.1.0, same with Material, same with CDK. I am seeing it manifest as:
Error: node_modules/ng2-charts/lib/base-chart.directive.d.ts:40:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type arguments.

40     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<BaseChartDirective<any, any, any>, "canvas[baseChart]",

Comment: @KarlBrown as seen below only upgrading to angular 15 was a solution for me.

Comment: I had those issues, but was running ng build --watch. Once I killed the watch and restarted, the errors went away. I also used npm i @angular/cdk@14 since I am using Angular 14. HTH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same issue.
Go with ngrx/component **14.3.2,** if you use Angular 14.
Or update directly to Angular 15.

Comment: Thank you so much. For reference - only upgrading to angular 15 worked in my case. My steps - i tried first option -> npm i @ngrx/component@14.3.2 Didn't work. Then in order to use angular 15 i needed node js version 16.13 -> nvm install 16.13 and typescript version 4.8 -> change package.json "typescript": "4.8" and run npm install. Then remaining ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15 and ng update @angular/material@15, because i had already angular material installed. Seems that datepicker is having some problems to appear but so far other components work.

Comment: Great that it is working for you. 
@ngrx/component@14.3.2 is not working for you, because you are using cdk & material version 15.

Comment: I was getting the OP's problem and installed v14.3.2 of the ngrx/component as directed above. Did not fix the problem. The good news - I was running ng build --watch. Once I restarted that, it built without any issues!  I don't think ng build --watch was meant to survive new npm installs.

Answer (score 34):

I had the same error after running, `ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cl1@14`. Some other packages were updated to `v15.04` in my `pacakge.json`. I'm guessing these are all dependencies I should have chained to the `ng update` command to have them all update evenly to v14. The solution was just to downgrade the versions of all packages that were in v15 to the v14-lst.

I think that because my `@angular/compiler` and `@angular/compiler-cli` had been updated to `v15` is what triggered the compilation error when running `ng serve`

**Update:**

Ran into this again after configuring all my linters.
I don't think you want to lint or check on build node modules unless you really need to. Having typescript check node modules is important especially if you don't want different packages or different copies of the same package having conflicting type declarations.
To solve this, under compiler options in your tsconfig.json add `skipLibCheck: true`

*tsconfig.json*

```json
{
    ...
    complilerOptions: {
        ...
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}
```

Here are the [official docs on skipLibCheck](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck)

Comment: Thanks. In Angular 16.0.5 it works after adding it under angularCompilerOptions in the tsconfig.json file.

Comment: My application is just for POC-DEMO purpose.. I dont need this for now. It worked after adding this.

Answer (score 4):

I am also facing the same issue,

```
**error ts2707: generic type 'ɵɵdirectivedeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type arguments.**
```

but *don't worry its quite simple to solve this problem:-*

you need to just update the angular from version 14 to 15.

the following command is

**command** :-

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force
```

then your application run as you expect!

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

This is a compatibility issue. If you installed any new package check their Github and their dependencies.

I had installed ng-bootstrap@14 and it required angular of version 15 but my project is angular 14 so i had to downgrade the package to 13 to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case- it solved by applying this command:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force
```

Then, remove '~' symbol from styles if it is there:

Replace `@import "~@coreui/coreui-pro/scss/coreui"`
with `@import "@coreui/coreui-pro/scss/coreui"`

Answer (score 1):

remove the `never` parameter at the end just after `false`.
Or Update your angular version.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the exact issue, I simply first update my NodeJS ( from 16 to 18 from NodeJS official website), later-on I also need to update my angular cli/ angular core from version 14 to 15.
command :-ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force
I need to put --allow-dirty --force because I was getting this error :-
Error: Repository is not clean. Please commit or stash any changes before updating.
and my application again starts running expectedly.

After doing all, my issue got resolved and my application again start's working expectedly.

Comment: Thank you, fortunately i already updated to angular 15 and did steps mentioned below, so i cannot try your option, but it might be very useful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the best solution, however I have to use `Angular 14` to make it work. I hacked the chart componenent definiton. I removed last "never" in `chart.component.d.ts` in `static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<ChartComponent definiton` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. One has only to upgrade Angular CLI: `ng update @angular/cli@15`. If you still get an error then run: `npm install ng2-charts --save --force`.
Charts will get installed.

Answer (score -3):

I found a TEMPORARY solution, i had a same error and i went inside node_modules and commented error lines.

In my case it was one comment in `node_modules/@angular/cdk/bidi/index.d.ts` and couple more in `node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/index.d.ts`, altho i do not know what caused this error and i dont know if comenting this lines will cause problems in the future, there ist need to explore it further.

Comment: commenting inside packages is nothing else than bad, please reconsider publishing such solution

Comment: i stated "temporary solution" and it temporary helped me so i will keep it here