# error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type arguments

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material, infinite-scroll, ngx-bootstrap

I installed `ngx-infinite-scroll` library using `npm install ngx-infinite-scroll --save` command. As provided in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll).
However, I am getting the following error in the library file: 
`Error: node_modules/ngx-infinite-scroll/lib/ngx-infinite-scroll.directive.d.ts:28:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type arguments`

**Screenshot :** [image]

Some already existing solutions:

- Found a similar error message question asked on stackflow itself : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74616687/error-ts2707-generic-type-%c9%b5%c9%b5directivedeclaration-requires-between-6-and-8-type) . But its in different library.
- One more identical one : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74802297/generic-type-%c9%b5%c9%b5componentdeclaration-requires-between-7-and-8-type-arguments). But as per the library I added, recommended solution is not helpful as I already have it for the lib.

Info about version that I have:
[image]

I read few more article but didnt found a concrete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using latest version of the **ngx-infinite-scroll** which is `15.0.0`, but my Angular version is `14`. 
 
So I downgraded ngx-infinite-scroll version to `14` using `npm install ngx-infinite-scroll@14.0.1` 
And error got resolved.

**ScreenShot:**
[image]